# Make cmd.exe exit on any error in a batch file

Tags: shell, batch, cmd.exe

On Unix shells, such as `sh` or `bash`, there is a `-e` flag that causes it to stop executing a script as soon as a command encounters an error.

Is there any equivalent for Windows CMD.EXE?
If not, why not -- it seems obviously useful?

I have done a lot of googling, but can't find any solution. Yet, it seems like such a major problem that I'd expect Microsoft to have added a solution at some point - they have not been afraid to enhance other aspects of CMD.

Comment: I think it depends on the type of error. There are some errors that are just unacceptable and cmd aborts immediately. Other types, not so much. And pretty much anytime, you can put in a line that says "if %errorlevel% neq 0 exit" But there is no -e that I'm aware of.

Comment: SomeCommand.exe || EXIT /B 1

Comment: it's possible in powershell [How to stop a PowerShell script on the first error?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9948517/995714), but in cmd you'll have to handle that yourself. You should use powershell for new code anyway

Comment: duplicate: [How do I make a batch file terminate upon encountering an error?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/734598/995714)

Comment: Hm, you're right phuclv.

Comment: Perhaps what I'm really asking is, *why* CMD.exe doesn't have such a feature, which would be opinion based I suppose